# In angular js 1.4.7 whether the object property/field name should start with string(number is not allowed)?

Tags: angularjs

In angular 1.2 it works fine if the object property name starts with number....

For example:{{Customer.1Name}} works fine in angular 1.2

but in angular 1.4.7 it is not allowed

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.1' is an unexpected token at column 9 of the expression [Customer.1Name] starting at [.1Name]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe dot notation only works for property names that are 'valid' identifiers. For anything else (numbers) you'd need to use bracket notation.
To be valid it would either need to start with a $, letter or be escaped.

for example:
var tObj = {foo:'a', 22:'b'};
console.log(tObj.foo, tObj[22], tObj["22"]);